# Check box issue

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that selects options associated with an image in a program for example there is an option for one projector or two with an appropriate image for each check box. I have called this subroutine when each checkbox is ticked but I wondering if I could check which had been ticked in the groupbox? just looking to make this more efficent

```
Sub chkValid()
    If chkRadioMic.Checked = True Then
        picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkFixedMic.Checked = True Then
        picFixedMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picFixedMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkMediaPlayer.Checked = True Then
        picMedia.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picMedia.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkLighting.Checked = True Then
        picLighting.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picLighting.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkRemote.Checked = True Then
        picRemote.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picRemote.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkRadioMic_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkRadioMic.CheckedChanged
    chkValid()
End Sub

Private Sub chkFixedMic_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkFixedMic.CheckedChanged
    chkValid()
End Sub

Private Sub chkMediaPlayer_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkMediaPlayer.CheckedChanged
    chkValid()
End Sub

Private Sub chkLighting_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLighting.CheckedChanged
    chkValid()
End Sub

Private Sub chkRemote_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkRemote.CheckedChanged
    chkValid()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but that is not the way to go. You could make it more efficient by grouping your controls to the same event using multiple `Handles`. This method also require no secondary subroutine. Like so:

```
Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkRadioMic.CheckedChanged, chkFixedMic.CheckedChanged, chkMediaPlayer.CheckedChanged, chkLighting.CheckedChanged, chkRemote.CheckedChanged
    If chkRadioMic.Checked = True Then
        picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkFixedMic.Checked = True Then
        picFixedMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picFixedMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkMediaPlayer.Checked = True Then
        picMedia.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picMedia.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkLighting.Checked = True Then
        picLighting.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picLighting.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    If chkRemote.Checked = True Then
        picRemote.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        picRemote.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: Alternatively you can try this way sleeker approach but I cannot guarantee it works as I have no way to try it at the moment:

```
Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkRadioMic.CheckedChanged, chkFixedMic.CheckedChanged, chkMediaPlayer.CheckedChanged, chkLighting.CheckedChanged, chkRemote.CheckedChanged
    Dim assPicBox as PictureBox = CType(("pic" & sender.Name.Remove(0,3)).ToString, PictureBox)
    If sender.Checked = True Then
        assPicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else
        assPicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this idea:

Form Load

```
chkRadioMic.tag= picRadioMic
chkFixedMic.tag= picFixedMic
chkMediaPlayer.tag= picMedia
chkLighting.tag= picLighting
chkRemote.tag= picRemote
```

New method:

```
Sub chkValid(p_check as checkbox, p_picRadioMic as picturebox)
   If p_check.Checked = True Then
      p_picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
   Else
      p_picRadioMic .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
   End If
End Sub
```

Single handler:

```
Private Sub chkRadioMic_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkRadioMic.CheckedChanged, chkFixedMic.CheckedChanged, chkMediaPlayer.CheckedChanged,chkLighting.CheckedChanged, chkRemote.CheckedChanged
chkValid(ctype(sender, checkbox),ctype(ctype(sender, checkbox).tag, picturebox) )
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not more efficient in terms of CPU cycles but for your eyes:

```
Dim allCheckedCheckBoxes = From chk in GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
                           Where chk.Checked
For Each chk As CheckBox in allCheckedCheckBoxes
 ' ... '
Next
```

If it's a single `CheckBox` you can use `First` or `FirstOrdefault`:

```
Dim checkedCheckBox As CheckBox = allCheckedCheckBoxes.FirstOrdefault()
If checkedCheckBox IsNot Nothing Then
  ' .. '
End if
```

Comment: The problem with your idea is that he won't be able to target different `ImageBox` controls to modify as he is doing right now. This, plus that you're forcing to check all the items when the event is triggered when only one is modified.